# Cordova 3 how to backup the web sql file

Tags: sqlite, backup, web-sql, cordova-3

what is actually the best solution or best practice to backup a web Sql file of a iOS / Android based App?

I have developed a routine to export the whole content of the sqlite tables in a collection of queries to re-populate and overwrite the database, which can be exported as a text and imported on another device. Example from iPhone to iPad. And it works like charm, via email. Plain text.

Cannot do it on Android since looks like there is a limit for the text you can send via email from the mobile device. So looking for a solution.

Please help, maybe there is a whole easy way I am not considering. Any idea appreciated.